# How to add a combobox item value in the string collection editor in C#?

Tags: c#, combobox

I can add an item and its value to a combobox with the following code.

```
combobox1.Items.add(new Item("text","value"));
```

How do I add a value to a text in string collection editor? I can only add text in the string collection editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you can only specify the text using the Visual Studio built-in editor.